# how to implement android drawe that slides from top of main activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I make the drawer appear from the top of the screen in android?
I can find any word about in on material.io

This solution is used in android chrome application.
It looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX9Kc.jpg

on second step:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rek7t.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom view, so basically think of using a BottomSheetDialogue. Give it a styling with the bottomLeftRadius and bottomRightRadius of 16dp.

Then position the Bottom sheet at the top of the screen using a WindowManager.That is one option.

For a more detailed in-depth solution

1. create a drawable shape that has rounded corners

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

2. In your styles.xml file. Go ahead and input this

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>


 <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/customCurvedBottomSheet</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customCurvedBottomSheet" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialogue</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">30dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">20dp</item>
    </style>
```

Now you've created a style for the bottom sheet to look like how you want it.

3. Go ahead and use a WindowManager for positioning it to the top, after you've implemented your bottom sheet.

```
Window window = bottomSheetDialogue.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = window.getAttributes();

layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
layoutParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(layoutParams);
```